# File System Watcher - watch not only file but also inside file

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

How to monitor a change in a file using a FileSystemWatcher

I have a folder with diseases and I want to display on the console not only the changes in the pack but also in the file (for example, .txt .doc ...) the changes
I use events (Create Delete Change) but its work only for folder, not inside file

Comment: So you want to do some sort of file diff?

Comment: *its work only for folder, not inside file* - but the last write time of an edited file changes, and FSW picks that up.. ?

Comment: FSW won't tell you what change was made inside the file, only that the file has changed. Either keep a copy of the file yourself and diff it every time you see a change.. or use something like git to see changes

Comment: @TheGeneral   I want output to console for example( Text in file write now)  Change (Text write not now)  and this change dedicate and output

Comment: @CaiusJard  
is it not possible to display changes in the file in real time to the console??

Comment: Depends what you mean by real time.

Comment: @Vadim your question is unclear. It's perfectly possible to display file changes. How you get them is another matter and *not* something that FSW can help with. Word and Excel files are binary files, just like JPG or GIF images. A `docx` is a ZIP package containing XML files. Changes include changes in formatting, not just text. Sure, you can use Word APIs to find retrieve versions and changes - provided versions are enabled. Or you could diff the individual XML documents, but the result wouldn't make much sense to a human. Or you can just calculate the byte differences

Comment: @Vadim what kind of changes do you want to track and what do you mean by `display on the console`? What are you trying to do? It matters. You may be able to use the file system's support to do what you want or not. NTFS for example supports journaling, file history and versioning, at least for shared folders

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos
Ok. U not understand me. I want program like FileSystemWatcher but for file content, not dir and her files 
if this exists then please tell me, mb exists some lib in .net

Comment: @CaiusJard runtime program, like FSW work in console

Comment: But that could be 5 minutes after the event, which isn't realtime in my book. Anyway.. Like I said, FSW will tell you when a file changes but it's up to you to go look inside it and find what has changed

Answer (score 1):

You can take a copy from files as a historical Repo and get old Content from it whenever you need

modified example from [original example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-6.0#examples)

```cs
class MyClassCS
{

    static HelperRepo repo;
    static void Main()
    {
        string SrcDir = @"D:\XRep";
        using var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(SrcDir);
        repo = new HelperRepo(SrcDir); // repo for history changes


        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes
                             | NotifyFilters.CreationTime
                             | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName
                             | NotifyFilters.FileName
                             | NotifyFilters.LastAccess
                             | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                             | NotifyFilters.Security
                             | NotifyFilters.Size;



        watcher.Changed += OnChanged;
        watcher.Created += OnCreated;
        watcher.Deleted += OnDeleted;
        watcher.Renamed += OnRenamed;
        watcher.Error += OnError;

        watcher.Filter = "*.txt";
        watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;


        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ChangeType != WatcherChangeTypes.Changed)
        {
            return;
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Changed: {e.FullPath}");
        // you can see the diff from your repo 

        var oldContent = repo.GetFileContent(e.FullPath);
        var newContet = File.ReadAllText(e.FullPath);
        Console.WriteLine($"new Content : {newContet}");
        Console.WriteLine($"old Content: {oldContent}");

        // reflect change in repo
        repo.ReflectFile(e.FullPath);


    }

    private static void OnCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        string value = $"Created: {e.FullPath}";
        Console.WriteLine(value);

        // reflect change in repo
        repo.ReflectFile(e.FullPath);

    }

    private static void OnDeleted(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Deleted: {e.FullPath}");

        // reflect change in repo
        repo.ReflectDelet(e.FullPath);
    }

    private static void OnRenamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Renamed:");
        Console.WriteLine($"    Old: {e.OldFullPath}");
        Console.WriteLine($"    New: {e.FullPath}");

        // reflect change in repo
        repo.ReflectRename(e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath);

    }

    private static void OnError(object sender, ErrorEventArgs e) =>
        PrintException(e.GetException());

    private static void PrintException(Exception? ex)
    {
        if (ex != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Message: {ex.Message}");
            Console.WriteLine("Stacktrace:");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            Console.WriteLine();
            PrintException(ex.InnerException);
        }
    }


}
```

### HelperRepo

```cs
class HelperRepo
{
    private readonly string _repoDir = @"D:\temp_repo";
    private readonly string _srcDir;

    public HelperRepo(string srcDir)
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(srcDir); // make sure that repo exist
        CopyFilesRecursively(srcDir, _repoDir);
        _srcDir = srcDir;
    }

    public string GetFileContent(string src_File)
    {
        var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(src_File) ?? "";
        if (!dir.StartsWith(_srcDir))
            throw new ArgumentException("inCorect Directory");
        var repoFile = src_File.Replace(_srcDir, _repoDir);
        return File.ReadAllText(repoFile);
    }

    public void ReflectFile(string src_File)
    {
        var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(src_File) ?? "";
        if (!dir.StartsWith(_srcDir))
            throw new ArgumentException("inCorect Directory");

        File.Copy(src_File, src_File.Replace(_srcDir, _repoDir), true);
    }

    public void ReflectDelet(string src_File)
    {
        var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(src_File) ?? "";
        if (!dir.StartsWith(_srcDir))
            throw new ArgumentException("inCorect Directory");

        File.Delete(src_File.Replace(_srcDir, _repoDir));
    }

    public void ReflectRename(string oldPath, string newPath)
    {
        ReflectDelet(oldPath);
        ReflectFile(newPath);
    }

    static void CopyFilesRecursively(string sourcePath, string targetPath)
    {
        //Now Create all of the directories
        foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(sourcePath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(sourcePath, targetPath));
        }

        //Copy all the files & Replaces any files with the same name
        foreach (string srcFile in Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            var targetFile = srcFile.Replace(sourcePath, targetPath);
            File.Copy(srcFile, targetFile, true);
        }
    }
}
```